# Converting PDF to SWF

Tags: java, linux, gwt, pdf, flash

I m trying to convert pdf to swf on Linux using Gwt.
For convertion i m using swftool.org.

In my convertion i m also combining the output swf with my viewer using cmd

pdf2swf Note.pdf -o Note.swf -B viewer.swf

my code is wokring properly at consol as well as in development mode but at hosted mode output file of swf is not combined with my viewer.swf 
It comes in the default swf form

here is my code ::

```
class swfconvertor
{
   String convertor(String kk, String pathname_dir, String newSWFfilename)
    {
    String s9="";

        try
        {
            Runtime Re=null;
            Re = Runtime.getRuntime();
            System.out.println("bharat 1");

            //Re.exec("chmod 777 test1.sh");
            Process s = Re.exec("/usr/local/bin/test1.sh");
            synchronized (s) 
            {
                s.wait(20000);
            }
            System.out.println("bharat 2");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));     

            System.out.println("buffer "+br.readLine());
            System.out.println("buffer "+br.readLine());
            System.out.println("buffer "+br.readLine());
            System.out.println("buffer "+br.readLine());

            s9=br.readLine();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            s9=e.toString();
        }

    return s9;
}
}
```

in test1.sh my code for convertion is present which is as ::

```
#!/bin/sh
```

`/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/ROOT/file/pdf2swf /usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/ROOT/file/c8fpB5eGNR.pdf -o /usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/ROOT/file/funn.swf -B /usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/ROOT/file/viewer.swf`

My Problem is that my this code is working properly in both development mode of GWT as well as on terminal. But do not provide expected output on hosted mode(when i deploy it on apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/ROOT/ server).

Thank you for your kind interest...!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to execution of multiple commands in single process.
In my test1.sh there are two commands executing at same time.
Due to which output of the first command which is input to second command is not generated and I was unable to get desired result.

I recommend to execute one command at a time.

Thanx and Regards